# What does 0in mean as a unit of measurement?

Tags: html, css

I'm going through the code on one of my school's canvas pages and I came across:

```
<p style="margin: 0in; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 9.0pt;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="margin: 0in; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 9.0pt;">&nbsp;</p>
```

Can someone explain what `0in` means? I can't find it on Google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) from MDN or [CSS Values and Units Module Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#absolute-lengths):

> in:   Inches

… and 0 is just zero.

Answer (score 0):

There are many units of size of margin in HTML such as px (pixel), rem, em, in, etc. The `margin: 0in` means that the margin has 0 inches from other HTML elements.